# ¿Cuál es el motivo de un loop infinito?

Tags: java, loops

Buenas a todos. Estoy tratando de realizar un buscaminas en java y tengo un problema que hasta que no solucione no puedo seguir avanzando. En este tramo de código se genera un loop infinito cuya causa no soy capaz de localizar.

```
public static void placeMines() {
    Random rn = new Random();
    int side = Setup.getSide();
    int mines = Setup.getMines();
    while (mines != 0) {
        int rnr = rn.nextInt(side);
        int rnc = rn.nextInt(side);
        int crrntvalue = Board.cells[rnr][rnc].getValue();
        if (crrntvalue < 9) {
            Board.cells[rnr][rnc].setValue(9);
            mines = mines - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

En donde `Side` es el lado del tablero (el cual es cuadrado), mines el numero de minas a colocar, `cells[][]` un array con la información de cada celda, y 9 el valor que toma la casilla en caso de tener una mina.

Lo que intento hacer es generar dos números aleatorios entre 0 y el valor del lado del tablero, y comprobar si en esa casilla se encuentra una mina.

En caso afirmativo se busca otra, y en caso negativo se coloca la mina y se disminuye el contador de minas restantes.

Comment: Puede que sea que mines alguna vez salte de 0 a -1, el while ponlo a >= 0

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas debug del código para entender el problema. Además, convendría saber que: 1) le asignas un valor a `mine` mayor a 0 y 2) que el número de casillas en tu matriz es o será mayor al número de minas que intentas colocar.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random r=new Random();
int dimension=Setup.getSide();
int minas= Setup.getMines();

if(minas > 0) {
  while(minas > 0) {
    int x=rn.nextInt();
    int y=rn.nextInt();
    int estado = Board.cells[x][y].getValue();
    if(estado != 9) { //supongo que todas las celdas estan a un valor diferente a 9
      Board.cells[x][y].setValue(9);
      minas --;
    }
  }
}
```

Creo que tu error es que las celdas estan inicializadas a un valor >= 9, como no cumple la condición no se disminuye nunca el valor minas

Answer (score 0):

Para que salga del While las minas han de llegar a 0.
Y para que lleguen a 0 el crrntvalue debe ser menor que 9....debes tener un fallo aquí:
   int crrntvalue = Board.cells[rnr][rnc].getValue();